# The curvature blows up

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, plane-curves, plane-geometry

A curve evolves according to the evolution equation $\displaystyle\frac{\partial X}{\partial t}= k \times N$ where $k$ is the curvature of the curve and $N$ is the inward unit normal  vector.

Then why when we hit a singulatity during the evolution process does the curvature $k $ blow up and tend to infinity ? We can consider if you want a convex plane curve.

Comment: You should think that curvature $k$ looks like the inverse radius of the "biggest ball" you can fit inside the curve. A singularity here would be a kink in the curve, since the biggest ball we could fit in the kink would be no ball at all...hence infinite curvature.

Comment: nice  answer thank u :) then when $k$ tends to infinity the evolution process stops but i was wondering if we have the following equation $\displaystyle\frac{\partial X}{\partial t}= -k \times N $ then whta would happen to the curve ? it will get smaller or bigger ?

Comment: @lilo: Nice question with the negative sign. Try it out  starting with, say, the unit circle.